# add a click handler to a quill object

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, quill

In Quill, I prepared a special span (just changing the background color) of some text. Now I would like to fire up a popup when a user clicks or double-clicks on that span. Doing that, it seems that Quill intercepts the event (which is not unexpected) but probably stops the propagation.
Is there a way to make Quill not stop the propagation and allow for remaining click handlers to be called ?

I tried a

```
$("#idOfMySpan").unbind('click');
```

before binding with my handler but it doesn't work.

Thanks !

Damir

Answer (score 0):

This is a little wacky, but have you tried hiding the real button, and using a decoy button to:

1. Trigger your custom event first.
2. Then, trigger the original, hidden button.

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged the thing and Quill is perfectly transmitting the events, I was able to do what I wanted. But I keep your idea, just in case... :-)
Thanks !